# changing the range / limits on a polar chart in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, polar-coordinates

I'm using Octave 4.0 using Linux which is similar to Matlab

Is it possible to have a different range of numbers on a polar chart and have them show up along with the degrees also?

The normal polar plot goes from 0-359 degrees `shown in black in image`, I would like the range and tick values to be from 0 to 100 `shown in red in the image` is this possible?  If so can two ranges be shown on a polar plot at the same time (0-359 and 0-100) almost like plotting 2 y axis using plotyy on the same plot?

See image below of polar plot
[image: Polar plot with two ranges of numbers]

Here's the the numbers 0-359 and there corresponding numbers 0-100 matching up.

```
0   0
1   0.27855
2   0.5571
3   0.83565
4   1.11421
5   1.39276
6   1.67131
7   1.94986
8   2.22841
9   2.50696
10  2.78552
11  3.06407
12  3.34262
13  3.62117
14  3.89972
15  4.17827
16  4.45682
17  4.73538
18  5.01393
19  5.29248
20  5.57103
21  5.84958
22  6.12813
23  6.40669
24  6.68524
25  6.96379
26  7.24234
27  7.52089
28  7.79944
29  8.07799
30  8.35655
31  8.6351
32  8.91365
33  9.1922
34  9.47075
35  9.7493
36  10.0279
37  10.3064
38  10.585
39  10.8635
40  11.1421
41  11.4206
42  11.6992
43  11.9777
44  12.2563
45  12.5348
46  12.8134
47  13.0919
48  13.3705
49  13.649
50  13.9276
51  14.2061
52  14.4847
53  14.7632
54  15.0418
55  15.3203
56  15.5989
57  15.8774
58  16.156
59  16.4345
60  16.7131
61  16.9916
62  17.2702
63  17.5487
64  17.8273
65  18.1058
66  18.3844
67  18.663
68  18.9415
69  19.2201
70  19.4986
71  19.7772
72  20.0557
73  20.3343
74  20.6128
75  20.8914
76  21.1699
77  21.4485
78  21.727
79  22.0056
80  22.2841
81  22.5627
82  22.8412
83  23.1198
84  23.3983
85  23.6769
86  23.9554
87  24.234
88  24.5125
89  24.7911
90  25.0696
91  25.3482
92  25.6267
93  25.9053
94  26.1838
95  26.4624
96  26.7409
97  27.0195
98  27.2981
99  27.5766
100 27.8552
101 28.1337
102 28.4123
103 28.6908
104 28.9694
105 29.2479
106 29.5265
107 29.805
108 30.0836
109 30.3621
110 30.6407
111 30.9192
112 31.1978
113 31.4763
114 31.7549
115 32.0334
116 32.312
117 32.5905
118 32.8691
119 33.1476
120 33.4262
121 33.7047
122 33.9833
123 34.2618
124 34.5404
125 34.8189
126 35.0975
127 35.376
128 35.6546
129 35.9331
130 36.2117
131 36.4903
132 36.7688
133 37.0474
134 37.3259
135 37.6045
136 37.883
137 38.1616
138 38.4401
139 38.7187
140 38.9972
141 39.2758
142 39.5543
143 39.8329
144 40.1114
145 40.39
146 40.6685
147 40.9471
148 41.2256
149 41.5042
150 41.7827
151 42.0613
152 42.3398
153 42.6184
154 42.8969
155 43.1755
156 43.454
157 43.7326
158 44.0111
159 44.2897
160 44.5682
161 44.8468
162 45.1253
163 45.4039
164 45.6825
165 45.961
166 46.2396
167 46.5181
168 46.7967
169 47.0752
170 47.3538
171 47.6323
172 47.9109
173 48.1894
174 48.468
175 48.7465
176 49.0251
177 49.3036
178 49.5822
179 49.8607
180 50.1393
181 50.4178
182 50.6964
183 50.9749
184 51.2535
185 51.532
186 51.8106
187 52.0891
188 52.3677
189 52.6462
190 52.9248
191 53.2033
192 53.4819
193 53.7604
194 54.039
195 54.3175
196 54.5961
197 54.8747
198 55.1532
199 55.4318
200 55.7103
201 55.9889
202 56.2674
203 56.546
204 56.8245
205 57.1031
206 57.3816
207 57.6602
208 57.9387
209 58.2173
210 58.4958
211 58.7744
212 59.0529
213 59.3315
214 59.61
215 59.8886
216 60.1671
217 60.4457
218 60.7242
219 61.0028
220 61.2813
221 61.5599
222 61.8384
223 62.117
224 62.3955
225 62.6741
226 62.9526
227 63.2312
228 63.5097
229 63.7883
230 64.0669
231 64.3454
232 64.624
233 64.9025
234 65.1811
235 65.4596
236 65.7382
237 66.0167
238 66.2953
239 66.5738
240 66.8524
241 67.1309
242 67.4095
243 67.688
244 67.9666
245 68.2451
246 68.5237
247 68.8022
248 69.0808
249 69.3593
250 69.6379
251 69.9164
252 70.195
253 70.4735
254 70.7521
255 71.0306
256 71.3092
257 71.5877
258 71.8663
259 72.1448
260 72.4234
261 72.7019
262 72.9805
263 73.2591
264 73.5376
265 73.8162
266 74.0947
267 74.3733
268 74.6518
269 74.9304
270 75.2089
271 75.4875
272 75.766
273 76.0446
274 76.3231
275 76.6017
276 76.8802
277 77.1588
278 77.4373
279 77.7159
280 77.9944
281 78.273
282 78.5515
283 78.8301
284 79.1086
285 79.3872
286 79.6657
287 79.9443
288 80.2228
289 80.5014
290 80.7799
291 81.0585
292 81.337
293 81.6156
294 81.8942
295 82.1727
296 82.4513
297 82.7298
298 83.0084
299 83.2869
300 83.5655
301 83.844
302 84.1226
303 84.4011
304 84.6797
305 84.9582
306 85.2368
307 85.5153
308 85.7939
309 86.0724
310 86.351
311 86.6295
312 86.9081
313 87.1866
314 87.4652
315 87.7437
316 88.0223
317 88.3008
318 88.5794
319 88.8579
320 89.1365
321 89.415
322 89.6936
323 89.9721
324 90.2507
325 90.5292
326 90.8078
327 91.0864
328 91.3649
329 91.6435
330 91.922
331 92.2006
332 92.4791
333 92.7577
334 93.0362
335 93.3148
336 93.5933
337 93.8719
338 94.1504
339 94.429
340 94.7075
341 94.9861
342 95.2646
343 95.5432
344 95.8217
345 96.1003
346 96.3788
347 96.6574
348 96.9359
349 97.2145
350 97.493
351 97.7716
352 98.0501
353 98.3287
354 98.6072
355 98.8858
356 99.1643
357 99.4429
358 99.7214
359 100
```

Here's an image of the numbers 0-359 and there corresponding numbers 0-100 matching up.
[Numbers matching up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SQTx.png)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I was going to post it as text but it would be so long how should I post it and what's the best way with all that data?

Comment: @AnderBiguri  Thanks I pasted it into a code block hopefully scrolling works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `polar` plot object in Octave adds the `rtick` and `ttick` properties to the parent axes which allows you to change the location of the ticks, however, there is unfortunately no `tticklabel` property that we can use to easily find and modify the theta tick marks.

Instead, we can plot your plot that you want the theta range to be 0 - 100 by first transforming your data to instead be 0 - 2*pi (as is expected by `polar`).  Then after plotting both, we can use `findall` to locate all text objects, figure out which ones are the theta ticks, create a copy of them and modify one of the sets to *appear to be* 0 - 100.

```
% Your first plot is going to use the 0 - 2pi range for theta
theta1 = linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000);
rho1 = sin(theta1 * 5);
plot1 = polar(theta1, rho1);

hold on

% For your second plot, just transform your 0 - 100 range to be 0 - 360 instead
theta2 = 0:100;
rho2 = linspace(0, 1, numel(theta2));
modtheta2 = 2*pi * (theta2 ./ 100);
plot2 = polar(modtheta2, rho2);

% Now we need to modify all of the labels

% Find all of the original labels
labels = findall(gca, 'type', 'text');

% Figure out which ones are the radial labels. To do this we compute the distance 
% from the center of the plot and find the most common distance
distances = cellfun(@(x)norm(x(1:2)), get(labels, 'Position'));

% Figure out the most common
[~, ~, b] = unique(round(distances * 100));
h = hist(b, 1:max(b));
labels = labels(b == find(h == max(h)));

% Make a copy of these labels (have to use arrayfun for 4.0.x compatibility)
blacklabels = arrayfun(@(L)copyobj(L, gca), labels);

% Shift these labels outward by 15%
arrayfun(@(x)set(x, 'Position', get(x, 'Position') * 1.15), blacklabels);

% Now set the other labels to red and change their values
set(labels, 'COlor', 'red')
for k = 1:numel(labels)
    value = str2num(get(labels(k), 'String'))

    % Convert the value to be between 0 and 100
    newvalue = 100 * (value / 360);

    set(labels(k), 'String', sprintf('%0.2f', newvalue))
end
```

[image]

Comment: I was waiting for your answer! What about an image to show the result?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Updated!

Comment: @Suever that looks great, but when I saved the code to a file to test it out in Octave 4.0 in Linux and I get this error. `error: Invalid call to strcmp.  Correct usage is:

 -- Built-in Function: strcmp (S1, S2)
error: called from
    print_usage at line 90 column 5
    copyobj at line 52 column 10
    test_multiaxis_polar_plot at line 31 column 13
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error: called from
    copyobj at line 52 column 10
    test_multiaxis_polar_plot at line 31 column 13`

Comment: @RickT Hmmm I'll look into it on that specific version of Octave.

Comment: @RickT Just updated the `copyobj` line so that it works in octave 4.0.x